# Create directive that wraps each list element inside a bootstrap panel with controls to delete, reorder, …

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an angularjs application that produces forms for lists of complex objects of the same structure. I wrote directives to create the html needed for editing them.

So its basically just a

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements">
    <div element-directive="element"></div>
</div>
```

However, I now want to add the possibility to reorder and delete each element in the list "elements" (and optionally add new ones)

Because I didn't want to implement control and logic over and over again for each type, I wrote a directive "repeatPanels" that should be used together with ngRepeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements" repeatPanels="elements">
    <div element-directive ng-model="element">
</div>
```

transforms the html to

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements" repeat-panels="elements"><div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">
      <div class="btn-group pull-left"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span></button></div>
      <div class="btn-group pull-right"><button ng-click="removeElement($index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></div></div><div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div element-directive ng-model="element">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="element in elements" repeat-panels="elements"><div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">
      <div class="btn-group pull-left"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span></button></div>
      <div class="btn-group pull-right"><button ng-click="removeElement($index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></div></div><div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div element-directive ng-model="element">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(see [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z1xzwB?p=preview)) for a complete example)

So it already wraps the html inside the ngRepeat inside a bootstrap panel, with buttons for deleting the element, and draggables for ui-sortable.

However, I'm stuck at implementing the functionality for the delete button. All the html inside the ng-repeat uses the "original" scope, so defining functions in the scope of the repeatPanels directive will not work :-(

For ui-sortable, I'm also not sure if simply adding the ui-sortable and ng-model attributes to the parent element of the original ng-repeat node work, or if there's more to do...

Is there somebody who could point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Florian

Answer (score 0):

First you need to $compile your custom template:

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

now, your inner template is bound to your isolate scope, so I moved ng-repeat into the custom template:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var panelHeadingHtml = '<div  class="panel-heading">' +
            '<div class="panel-title">' +
            '<div class="btn-group pull-left">' +
            '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span></button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="btn-group pull-right">' +
            '<button ng-click="removeElement($index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
            '</div>';
        element.wrapInner('<div ng-repeat="element in repeatPanelsElements"  class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"></div></div>');
        element.find(" > .panel").prepend(panelHeadingHtml);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
```

This changes the html to:

```
<div class="element" repeat-panels="elements">
```

One cost of this is that you have lost some flexibility to your implementation of ng-repeat.

Another cost is that the outer scope no longer communicates with the isolate scope directly, so you'll probably need to create events like:

```
scope {
    onDelete: '&'
}
```

to make calls to the persistence layer, for example.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/g8POHa?p=preview) here.